# returning a function value inside an iterator without exiting in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, iteration

I am not sure if my title fits my question but here it goes.

I have an iterator runs every 1 second and a function that goes like this:

```
function getValue(val) {
  return val;
}

function test() {
  let x = 20;
  getValue(x)

  setTimeout(()=>{
    test()
  }, 1000)
}

export default test;
```

When the function `getValue()` is hit, the iterator stops because there is a return inside that function. How do I return the value without exiting stopping the iteration? Is there a way? Thanks a lot.

---

index.js (reactjs)

```
import test from './test.js';

componentDidMount() {
  test()
}
```

---

test.js

```
function getValue(val) {
  return val;
}

function test() {
  let x = 20;
  getValue(x)

  setTimeout(()=>{
    test()
  }, 1000)
}

export default test;
```

My Aim here is to pass/return the value 20 to my index.js

Comment: I don't see any [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) in your code. What do you mean? What "stops" or "exits", and where do you (want to) "return" to? What is your [actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: Aren't you mistaking `setTimeout` with `setInterval`?

Comment: @Bergi - the iterator is the test function, the setTimeout() inside test function will execute the test() every 1sec . . you see it executes itself every 1sec.

Comment: @Chinito - if I move the setTimeout() outside it will no longer iterate.

Comment: @AurelianoFarSuau - yeah . . . hhhmmm I think setInterval can do the trick . . let me try . . thanks a lot.

Comment: @WebsiteIsFun Yes, it runs at a steady 1 second *interval*, but there is no *iterator*. Still, what is your problem? The interval doesn't stop. The `return` is in `getValue` function (and returns from the `getValue()` call), not in the `test` function. Everything works, doesn't it?

Comment: Please show us where / how you are calling `test` and what results you expect from it.

Comment: @Bergi - I have now updated the question with further details, please check thank you.

Comment: The return value inside `getValue` would not cause the iteration to stop, but your `test()` function doesn't do anything that's observable outside of itself.

Comment: Please read [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because an XY problem is precisely what you are asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My Aim here is to pass/return the value 20 to my index.js

For that, you don't need a `getValue` function. Just write

```
// test.js
export default function test() {
  let x = 20;
  setTimeout(test, 1000)
  return x; // <===
}
```

```
// index.js
import test from './test.js';
console.log("test() returned", test());
```

Notice that also in the timeout you will get that return value now, and can use it if you care

```
// test.js
export default function test() {
  let x = 20;
  setTimeout(() => {
    let res = test();
    console.log("test() in timeout returned", res);
  }, 1000)
  return x;
}
```

---

> any other options to this like it can pass value to the client every 1sec?

For that, you want to use a callback that is passed as a parameter to `test` and can be called to pass the value of `x` where- and whenever you want - and as often as necessary:

```
// test.js
export default function test(callback) {
//                           ^^^^^^^^
  let x = 20;
  callback(x); // <===
  setTimeout(() => {
    test(callback);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```
// index.js
import test from './test.js';
function gotValue(val) {
  console.log("received ", val);
}
test(gotValue);
//   ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: yes, it worked; however, it returned once . . I does not return again . . the purpose if setTimeout() is to stop the operation for 1sec and then execute the test() again after 1sec rest.

Comment: @WebsiteIsFun A function cannot return multiple times from the same call.

Comment: @lightshadowninja There's not problem with using `setTimeout` recursively, especially when you want to adjust the timing or want to end it conditionally. And you can still trivially cancel it by storing the id of the current timeout.

Comment: I see, if it can not return when you call it again then I guess this answers the question . . :) thanks a lot . . Anyways, are any other options to this like it can pass value to the client every 1sec?

Comment: Cooooool . . just what I was looking for . . thanks a lot so much . .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to receive a value from test every interval, then you need to pass a callback function that will be executed each time.  It is simply not possible to return a value from a function multiple times (without a generator function, but that's not worth worrying about now).

```
const test = (callback) => {
    let x = 20;
    return setInterval(() => callback(x), 1000);
}

// then from elsewhere
// the lambda function will be called with x as 20
// every time the interval fires
const unsub = test((x) => {
   // do something with x
   // unsubscribe when you are ready and the interval will be cleared
   if (condition) {
       clearInterval(unsub);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question.

You don't seem to iterate (loop) at all in your function.

My suggestion is either to return at the very end of your function, or to make your function have no return statement, and instead change a value of a var to the desired type.  If you want to give multiple values as your return, simply on of the two above options with an array that contains all desired values.

Comment: yeah this was my initial idea; however, I am not sure how to pass the value to the client side if I do not return it. Thanks